# 1991年生まれと1981年生まれの人数を調べたい。

Tags: mysql, sql

## やりたい事

1991年生まれと、1981年生まれの有名人が何人いるか調べてください。ただし、日付関数は使用せず、UNION句を使用してください。

[image: Image from Gyazo]

## コード

```sql
SELECT 
COUNT(birth),
SUBSTRING(birth,1,4) AS '誕生年'
FROM 
`celebrities` 
WHERE birth >= '1991/1/1' AND birth <= '1991/12/31'
UNION
SELECT 
COUNT(birth),
SUBSTRING(birth,1,4) AS '誕生年'
FROM 
`celebrities` 
WHERE birth >= '1981/1/1' AND birth <= '1981/12/31'
```

## 現状

SUBSTRINGで、誕生年数を切り出す事は出来ました。
後はカウント関数で数を変えるだけだと思った所、このようなエラーが出てしまいます。
分かる方居ましたらお願いします

```
#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'world.celebrities.birth'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: この場合、まず解決すべきは「条件に一致した結果の **件数** を数える」じゃないでしょうか？

Comment: `UNION`はできていますので、次のステップは「1.`birth`の日付文字列から誕生年のみを切り出す」ことと「2.誕生年の該当人数をカウントする」ことの2つです。これら2つの課題のどちらかは自力で解決できますか？現在のコードでは`birth`カラムをそのまま表示していて、困っている具体的な箇所が分かりにくく感じます。例えば「`SUBSTRING`で誕生年を切り出そうとしてSQLを○○に書き換えたところ、XXのエラーが出た」「集計関数の`COUNT`を使うためSQLを○○に書き換えたところ、XXのエラーが出た」のように質問を具体化することで、的確な回答を得やすくなります。焦点を絞るように質問を編集してみてください。

Comment: 前回も指摘され修正しているのになぜ画像を使い続けるのでしょうか？ 質問者自身がもっと質問に向き合ってください。

Comment: SUBSTRINGで誕生年を切り出すことができまして、カウントした所エラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: [SQL練習問題 - 問70 | TECH PROjin](https://tech.pjin.jp/blog/2017/09/30/sql%E7%B7%B4%E7%BF%92%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C-%E5%95%8F70/)

Answer (score 0):

`count`などの集計関数には初心者に分かりにくい特徴がありまして、**集計対象外のカラム**をselectしたい場合には`group by`が必要になります。
ただし今回の設問では`UNION`の使用を条件としているので、コメントのリンク先を書き換えた下記の回答を意図しているのかもしれません。

```
SELECT '1991' AS '誕生年', COUNT(id)
FROM celebrities
WHERE SUBSTRING(birth, 1, 4) = '1991'
UNION
SELECT '1981', COUNT(id)
FROM celebrities
WHERE SUBSTRING(birth, 1, 4) = '1981'
```

ご質問のように、`substring`で誕生年を取得する素直な対応方法として下記のSQLも`group by`を使用して同様の結果を導けます。
(習っていないであろうwith句を使っている時点で若干素直ではないですが)

```
with bys
as  (select  id,  substring(birth, 1, 4) '誕生年'
     from    celebrities)
select 誕生年,
       count(1)
from   bys
where  誕生年 = 1991
group by 誕生年
union all
select 誕生年,
       count(1)
from   bys
where  誕生年 = 1981
group by 誕生年
order by 誕生年
```